# Create list from serveral oclumns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, concatenation

I have the following dataframe:

```
name      age   year   salary1   salary2   salary3  salary4
Rodrigo   28    2021   1945       2312     4567     3214
Neil      26    2021   3546       6657     -3200    1855
Loti      34    5500   4671       3895     5512     7864
...
```

I would like to create new column that will have list of values of the column salary1,salary2,salary3 and salary4 , when this is the result output:

```
name      age   year   salary1   salary2   salary3  salary4     new_colum
Rodrigo   28    2021   1945       2312     4567     3214        [1945,2312,4567,3214]
Neil      26    2021   3546       6657     -3200    1855        [3546,6657,-3200,1855]
Loti      34    2021   4671       3895     5512     7864        [4671,3895,5512,7864]
```

I have tried to concat the relevant column by change the type of each column to string and then add them:

```
df['new_column'] = df['salary1'].astype(str) + ',' + \
                   df['salary2'].astype(str) + ',' + \
                   df['salary3'].astype(str) + ',' + \
                   df['salary4'].astype(str)
```

that indeed concat the columns but does not make them  a list and also change the type to string while I still need it numerical.

**My questionn is how can I cerate new column with  list of the four column values?**

Comment: `df['new_column'] = df[['salary1', 'salary2', 'salary3', 'salary4']].values.tolist()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['new_column'] = df[['salary1', 'salary2', 'salary3', 'salary 4']].values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility using `apply` is

```
df['new_col'] = df[['salary1', 'salary2', 'salary3', 'salary4']].apply(lambda r: list(r), axis=1)
```

Note however that this is probably slower than using `.values.tolist()` instead of  `.apply`  as suggested in another answer.